# rdf4j on IntelliJ IDE?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, rdf, semantic-web

Extreme beginner here trying to work on RDF. Can rdf4j work on IntelliJ IDEA or it works on Eclipse only? If it can work on IntelliJ, could anyone show me how?

Comment: rdf4j is just a Java API - it will work in whatever IDE or Java environment you want to use. It's the same like you would ask if Google Guava or whatever works in IntelliJ

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

[RDF4J](https://rdf4j.org/) is a library that can be used within any Java IDE such as [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), [Eclipse IDE](https://www.eclipse.org/ide/) or [NetBeans](https://netbeans.apache.org/).

If you use IntelliJ IDEA, you can import the project from GitHub using the menu `Git -> Clone ...` and using `https://github.com/eclipse/rdf4j` as the URL.

You can then open an example, by navigating in the Project window to `rdf4j -> examples -> src -> main -> java -> org.eclipse.rdf4j.examples -> model` and then right click on the green arrow, on the left of the source code, to run it.

[image]